# Rails Stripe checkout with custom amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a simple checkout with Rails using Stripe.
Based on option selected/button clicked the user will be charged a different amount, change description and listing id e.g.

```
<%= link_to "Pay To Activate", 
new_charge_path(:id => listing.id, :amount => 123, :desc => "Option A"), 
class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm", :method=> :get %>
```

When I send this to the ChargesController I'm getting amount, description and id from the parameters:

```
http://localhost:3000/charges/new?amount=123&desc=Option+A&id=45
```

Obviously this is not secure because the user can change the amount in URL.

create action looks as below:

```
def create
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => @description,
    :currency    => 'eur'
  )

  redirect_to thankyou_path

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```

How should I changed my code to make it more secure?

Comment: I think part of the issue might be that you're setting the amount in the view instead of the controller. The [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/rails) show the amount being saved in the create action.

Answer (score 0):

Based on experts comment payment process function have to model.

On the `payment` model I don't know what model actually using for payment, by the way, anything like that

```
#=> model.rb

def process_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create email: email, card: token
    Stripe::Charge.create customer: customer.id, amount: 1000, description: 'Premium', currency: 'usd' #=> 1000 means 10 USD
end
```

Controller

```
@payment = Payment.new({ email: params[:stripeEmail],
                        token: params[:stripeToken]
                    })

begin
   @payment.process_payment
   @payment.save
   redirect_to thankyou_path
rescue Exception => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  @payment.destroy
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```

I think to create a problem when you try to implement this formula that's why to make best common sense and create a secure payment. I need to say this is not accurate for your use because I don't know your project structure this is just a formula for a secure payment.

Thanks

Hope to help